# Overriding a variable within another function JS

Tags: javascript, git

Is it possible for me to call a function then override the contents of the variable before actually running it?

So I have a function that basically pulls in my Git profile like this:

```
var GetGitInfo = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var gitURL = "https://api.github.com/users/myself/repos";

    xhr.open("GET", gitURL);
    xhr.send(null);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
        var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
        if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === OK) {
                // console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            } else {
                console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Then I call the function in another step by doing `GetGitInfo();` which all works fine.

However, If I wanted to call the function and replace the `gitURL` variable how would I achieve that?

So something like

```
GetGitInfo(
  gotURL= "https://api.github.com/users/new_user/repo";
);
```

Comment: So something like `GetGitInfo([gitURL = "new_url"]);` @GerardoFurtado

Comment: Oh, just read the below answers, ignore my last point :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify a local variable to a function from outside the function.  They are private to the function's implementation.

But, since it's your own function, you can just create an argument that can be passed into the function.  You can even make the argument optional so it will take your initial value as the default value if it is not passed.

```
var GetGitInfo = function(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var gitURL = url || "https://api.github.com/users/myself/repos";

    xhr.open("GET", gitURL);
    xhr.send(null);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
        var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
        if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === OK) {
                // console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            } else {
                console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Then, you can use the function the way you were using it or you can pass in an URL to use:

```
getGitInfo();                    // uses your default URL
getGitInfo("http://someURL");    // uses the URL you pass in
```

FYI, this function looks like it will ultimately need to either return a promise or accept a callback so you can communicate the results back to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

From the snippet above you need to set the url as a function parameter so when calling it uses the specified url.

```
var GetInfo = function(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send(null);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
        var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
        if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === OK) {
            // console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        } else {
            console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status);
        }
    }
};

GetInfo("https://api.github.com/users/myself/repos");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do a toString() on the function:

`GetGitInfo.toString()`

Then you should do a text search and replace on the variable and it's data:

`GetGitInfo.toString().substring(0,GetGitInfo.indexOf('somestring'))+'gitUrl="newURL"'+GetGitInfo.toString().substring(.......)`

Then you should eval that string!

Or, you know, use function parameters. Either way. Whatever's easiest.

Comment: From what I read, the `responseText` actually takes the XML and turns it into a string. That's why i've turned it into a JSON object so I can iterate over it and so some logic. I'm still learning this though so I could be wrong, don't quite me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameters

```
var getData = function(url){
     // url can be used here
 }

var data = getData("http://apiurl.xy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a parameter to the function:

```
var GetGitInfo = function(gitURL) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", gitURL);
    xhr.send(null);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
        var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
        if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === OK) {
                // console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            } else {
                console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    };
}
GetGetInfo("https://api.github.com/users/myself/repos");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a parameter to your function:

```
var GetGitInfo = function(gitURL) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", gitURL);
    xhr.send(null);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
        var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
        if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === OK) {
                // console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            } else {
                console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
   };
```

}

and call it like this:

```
GetGitInfo("https://api.github.com/users/myself/repos");
```